# Maintenance.lock file persist intermittently during Azure PaaS Deployment

Tags: paas

While deploying the CI/CD process with Sitecore 9 ARM Template, Maintenace.lock file came up when the Sitecore instance is started.

Talked to Microsoft Azure Dev Ops team and they pointed to us the following:

https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Commerce/90/Sitecore%20Experience%20Commerce%2090%20Initial%20Release/Release%20Notes

> >
>   Deploying to an Azure App Service may fail intermittently when deploying all of Sitecore XP, Sitecore XC, SXA, and SXA Storefront, and when "deployExmDds" is set to true. This occurs because the bootloader does not correctly remove the locks after has finished processing. Workaround: remove “App_Data\Maintenance_lock”. And if it exists, remove file "app_offline.htm". And, if file "default.htm" gets renamed to "default.htm.sitedown" then rename it back to "default.htm".

We are not really using E-Commerce and deployExmDds parameter is set to false in ARM template parameters.

Please let us know if you have come across a solution. Thanks.

Additional Notes:

When we have a look at the InstallJob.log under the D:\home\LogFiles the following were written:

> 1 2019-01-30 23:09:03,686 INFO  Putting lock    1 2019-01-30
>   23:09:03,767 INFO  Putting lock, done    1 2019-01-30 23:09:03,811
>   INFO  Executing processor
>   Sitecore.Cloud.Integration.Bootload.InstallJob.Processors.InstallAppOfflineProcessor
>   1 2019-01-30 23:42:23,281 INFO  Putting lock    1 2019-01-30
>   23:42:23,359 INFO  Putting lock, done    1 2019-01-30 23:42:23,390
>   INFO  Executing processor
>   Sitecore.Cloud.Integration.Bootload.InstallJob.Processors.InstallAppOfflineProcessor
>   1 2019-01-30 23:42:28,453 INFO  Executing processor
>   Sitecore.Cloud.Integration.Bootload.InstallJob.Processors.InstallAppOfflineProcessor,
>   done    1 2019-01-30 23:42:28,505 INFO  Executing processor
>   Sitecore.Cloud.Integration.Bootload.InstallJob.Processors.PackageInstallProcessor
>   1 2019-01-30 23:42:28,562 INFO  Installing package
>   D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\Transforms\WFFM.Cloud.Embed.CaptchaHandlers.sccpl
>   1 2019-01-30 23:42:28,896 INFO  Installing package
>   D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\Transforms\WFFM.Cloud.Embed.CaptchaHandlers.sccpl,
>   done    1 2019-01-30 23:42:28,922 INFO  No packages to install,
>   shutting down    1 2019-01-30 23:42:28,955 INFO  Executing processor
>   Sitecore.Cloud.Integration.Bootload.InstallJob.Processors.PackageInstallProcessor,
>   done    1 2019-01-30 23:42:28,969 INFO  Executing processor
>   Sitecore.Cloud.Integration.Bootload.InstallJob.Processors.RemoveAppOfflineProcessor
>   1 2019-01-30 23:42:29,031 INFO  Executing processor
>   Sitecore.Cloud.Integration.Bootload.InstallJob.Processors.RemoveAppOfflineProcessor,
>   done    1 2019-01-30 23:42:29,281 INFO  Releasing lock    1 2019-01-30
>   23:42:29,312 INFO  Releasing lock, done

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's a Bootloader fails to install some module. Most likely it's a post step run failure. You can find installation logs in `d:\home\LogFiles\InstallJob.log`

Modules defined in `azuredeploy.json`, `parameters\modules`. After template run, transformations and post step info is stored under `App_Data\Transforms`.

You can delete `Maintenance_lock`, `app_offline.htm`- Sitecore will start and retry module installation.

Comment: Thanks @michael We'll have a look at the InstallJob.log next time and let you know.

Comment: We had a look at the InstallJob.log. See above: I am not sure why sometimes it worked and sometimes it doesn't.